# remove interword spacing lyx

Tags: lyx

I have a LyX document that I imported from a TeX document. It contains a bunch of interword spaces (that make it have two spaces after the period) that I would like to remove (all at once). How can this be done other than manually removing them all?

The document looks like this

```
hi hey hello. \ bye bye
```

Comment: Let's see what causes them first. Can you copy the relevant code from LyX > View > Source. A few words before and after the place where this happens.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip: edited. there is basically a `\` there

Comment: Find and replace. Your editor can do this. This is, incidentally, why you ought not add additional space between sentences in this way. (I take it you mean this space and not the interword space as you said. That would be the space between words within sentences, for example.) If the document was coded correctly, you would not need to replace all of them. However, it isn't really hard to do that. As I say, just use your editor. Or `sed` if you prefer.

Comment: @cfr: is there a way to do this in lyx? you are saying i can do a find and replace in lyx or do you mean edit the tex code directly before importing into lyx?

Comment: I wouldn't know. I assume LyX has some sort of facility for find and replace, but I've never used it.

Comment: @Alex did LyX add these spaces? Or were they already in the TeX document? If LyX added them that seems like a bug.

Comment: @Alex note that .lyx files are just text files. So you can use any find/replace commands to remove them. If you are on Linux, this should be easy to do with `sed`.

Comment: ...and bugs should be filed with the [LyX bug tracker](http://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome).

Comment: @scottkosty: they were already in the .tex file and not a LyX bug. the problem with find/replace is that i only want to replace the slash character and space character when it appears in the text. i'm afraid it might be in other places (it's a long paper) and i don't want to touch those... regex?

Comment: @Alex you can do that with LyX's "Advanced Find". Go to Edit > Find & Replace (Advanced).